# Windows 8 Mail app doesn't work with Gmail when 2-step verification is enabled

Tags: windows-8, gmail, windows-mail

I'm unable to link my Gmail account to Windows 8 Mail app when I have 2-step verification enabled on my Google account. The error message that's given is: "That email address or password didn't work." Disabling 2-step verification on my Google account fixes the problem. I guess this is really more of a bug report than a question, but I would love to hear if anybody else has a workaround that doesn't require me disabling the security on my Gmail account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is actually a simple way to get your GMail acount to work with Windows 8 Mail App even with 2-step verification enabled. You'll just have to use Application Specific password.

1. Go to your Google Account settings. You must be logged in: https://www.google.com/settings/account
2. Click on **Security** from the **Accounts** tab.
3. In the **Authorizing applications and site** section click on **Edit** button
4. Scroll down. At the bottom you'll see the section **Application-specific passwords**. Type a **Name** click on **Generate Passwords**.
5. You'll be given a password. Use that password with Windows 8 Mail App.

Comment: Ooh! I like this! Great solution!

Comment: @aardvarkk it is the only one.

Comment: @xander This is true, but if you uncheck the contacts and and calendar data it will function.

Comment: @xandercoded See my answer below for the new method.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is that it's failing because [Google recently deactivated Exchange ActiveSync](http://www.zdnet.com/gmail-loses-google-sync-how-windows-8-rt-office-are-affected-7000008846/) for free Gmail accounts.  Try un-checking the option to include contact and calendar data, which makes the Mail app use IMAP instead of EAS.

Comment: I appreciate you adding this. This is what worked for me. Once I unchecked the option you mentioned, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app password for the Mail app at gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a 2015 solution, this method worked for me.

1. Use the process outlined by [Rakib](https://superuser.com/a/494173/459041) to generate an app-specific password.
2. Remove your Google account from Windows Mail.
3. Add an account under Settings > Accounts using **Other account**, NOT Google. You can't use the Google interface to login, you MUST be prompted for your email and password in a native Windows form.
4. Enter your Google email and **app password** when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, you have to use a "Application-specific passwords" if you have one, otherwise you need to create one. You can learn more about that [here](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=ch_b/0/SmsAuthConfig&answer=185833).

Basically you are going to go to your security settings where you enabled 2-step authentication, and select edit, scroll down to the bottom and click the link that says "Manage application-specific passwords"

Scroll all the way to the bottom of that page and generate a new password, after giving it a name

That is the password you will use in Windows Mail.